# Passing global variables to dispatch router library php

Tags: php, global-variables, router, dispatch

So I'm using [noodlehaus / dispatch](https://github.com/noodlehaus/dispatch) for my website routhing. I want to pass some variables from main scope like `$currentLang` to `route(...)`, but I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: currentLang in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\_PERSONAL\newSite\index.php on line 18

Here's a part of my code.

```
require './functions/dispatch.php';

$currentLang = 'en';

route('GET', '/resume', function () {
    $data['lang'] = $currentLang;

    return response(
        phtml(__DIR__.'/views/resume', ['data' => $data ])
    );
});

dispatch();
```

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `global $data;` solved the problem:

```
    require './functions/dispatch.php';

    $currentLang = 'en';

    route('GET', '/resume', function () {
        global $currentLang;
        $data['resume'] = json_decode(
            file_get_contents("assets/json/resume-".$currentLang.".json"), true
        );

        return response(
            phtml(__DIR__.'/views/resume', ['data' => $data ])
        );
    });
```

Or like this:

```
    require './functions/dispatch.php';

    $currentLang = 'en';

    route('GET', '/resume', function () use ($currentLang){
        $data['resume'] = json_decode(
            file_get_contents("assets/json/resume-".$currentLang.".json"), true
        );

        return response(
            phtml(__DIR__.'/views/resume', ['data' => $data ])
        );
    });
```